# Converting Date time formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

What's the best way to convert date time formats using javascript?

I have this..  "2015-08-06T00:39:08Z"
and would like to change it to

"06/08/2015 12:39pm"

Comment: is the first string 08--MM or DD?

Comment: Should't your answer be 12:39 am instead of pm??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually by instantiating a Date object:

```
var d = new Date('2015-08-06T00:39:08Z');
```

Then using the Date methods (like `getDay` or `getUTCFullYear`) to get the information needed and build the formatted string.

Or, if you don't mind relying on a library, you could use http://momentjs.com/ that provides a lot of methods, and particularly the `format` method: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```
// Example with moment.js
var formattedDate = moment('2015-08-06T00:39:08Z').format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mma");
alert(formattedDate);
```

Comment: I went with moment.js. Very cool library. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

Use newDate() method, then Date Get Methods. Examples are explained on w3Schools

Method  Description

```
            getDate()   Get the day as a number (1-31)
            getDay()    Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
            getFullYear()   Get the four digit year (yyyy)
            getHours()  Get the hour (0-23)
            getMilliseconds()   Get the milliseconds (0-999)
            getMinutes()    Get the minutes (0-59)
            getMonth()  Get the month (0-11)
            getSeconds()    Get the seconds (0-59)
            getTime()   Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure javascript:

code:

```
function formatDate(input) {
    var datePart = input.match(/\d+/g),
        year = datePart[0], // get only two digits
        month = datePart[1],
        day = datePart[2];
    var h = parseInt(input.substr(input.indexOf("T") + 1, 2));
    var m = parseInt(input.substr(input.indexOf(":") + 1, 2));
    var dd = "AM";
    if (h >= 12) {
        h = hh - 12;
        dd = "PM";
    }
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    }
    m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
    alert(day + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + h.toString() + ':' + m.toString() + dd);
}

formatDate('2015-08-06T00:39:08Z'); // "18/01/10"
```